# Emplace directly in std::map of pair

Tags: c++, dictionary, c++14, std-pair, emplace

Why this code won't compile?

```
std::map<int,std::pair<int,int>> m;
m.emplace(1,1,1);
```

Assuming that we can edit the code of `std::map::emplace`, is it possible to alter it in order to make previous code valid?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is invalid for exactly the same reason this is invalid:

```
std::pair<const int, std::pair<int, int>> p{1, 1, 1};
```

Because the above is, in essence, what the map's `emplace` boils down to.

To make it work, you can use the [`piecewise_construct` constructor  of `std::pair`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair), which was introduced for precisely this purpose:

```
m.emplace(
  std::piecewise_construct,
  std::forward_as_tuple(1),
  std::forward_as_tuple(1, 1)
);
```

This will have the desired effect of not calling any unnecessary constructors (even if they would likely be elided).

---

To answer your hypothetical question about making the "direct" syntax work: in the general case for an arbitrary `map<K, V>`, no. Imagine this:

```
struct Proof {
  Proof(int);
  Proof(int, int);
};

std::map<Proof, Proof> m;
m.emplace(1, 1, 1);  // Now what?
```

You could certainly make it work for the limited case of `map<T, std::pair<T, T>>`. It would probably be doable for something a bit more general too, with the help of *massive* amounts of advanced template tricks (think [SFINAE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Substitution_failure_is_not_an_error) left, right, and centre, and then some). Whether that is worth it depends on the details of your situation.

Comment: In the general case, you just also need your classes to support piecewise constructors